# How to correctly load Jquery in Joomla 3.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, joomla3.0

I have searched all over. They are saying the correct syntax to load jquery in normal mode is `JHtml::_('jquery.framework', false);`

I have tried and failed. I need to load jQuery so it works on all pages, so where should i put this inside the template index.php file? in head? above the head? does it need to be wrapped inside  or not? I just need this to be spoon-fed to me because most forums assume people would already know where to put it...thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options. You can either call it normally which is exactly the same as the code you provided above, or you can all it in noConflict mode which is simply like this:

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
```

This code should be place in the template's *index.php* file and can be placed anywhere as it will automatically be appended to the `<head>` tags of your template. As this is PHP code, it of course needs to go inside `<?php ?>` tags.

Comment: ok i added <?php JHtml::_('jquery.framework', false); ?> inside the head, but it still does not work when i call the function.

Comment: have you checked the browser console to see if jquery is being loaded from the media folder?

Comment: I realized that I had to use jQuery instead of "$" because of the conflict in the normal mode. It works now.